# How to determine positions of groups on compound based on H-NMR spectroscopy (C9H13NO)

Tags: aromatic-compounds, molecular-structure, nmr-spectroscopy

Based on the below $\pu{200 MHz}$ $\ce{^1H}$-$\mathrm{NMR}$ spectroscopy, I have to determine the molecular structure of compound $\bf{B}$, which oxidises to a compound $\bf{A}$ with molecular formula $\ce{C9H11NO}$.

[image: H-NMR spectroscopy]

I am pretty sure compound $\bf{B}$ will then be $\ce{C9H13NO}$.
I know how to look at peaks and thereby neighbours, integral and thereby hydrogens on group in total.
From the shift, peaks, and integral I believe the group furthest downfield to be an aromatic (benzene) ring.
From this I am down to the following 3 possible compounds (ignoring chirality), but I'm unsure of how to determine with the shift by hand (no simulating software).

[image]
[image]
[image]

The following experiments have been done on compound **A**:

2,4-DNPH -> Red sediment -> carbonyl-group

Fehling -> no sediment -> not aldehyde, but ketone

Br(aq) -> no decolouration -> no C=C

Polaroid -> light shines through -> presence of asymmetric C-atom

Comment: None of these structures matched the spectrum. For example, how do you explain the two-proton sharp singlet at  around $\pu{2.0 ppm}$?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you calculated number of unsaturations first since you have the molecular formula.

Comment: I believe that singlet to be -NH2. From experiment with Br we find that there should be no C=C bonds.

Comment: Can't be the third one because **A** would be an amide, and 2,4 DNPH would not react with it.

Comment: You have found the presence of carbonyl group. but, where is the carbonyl group in your structures?

Comment: The third compound is not isolable but an intermediate.

Comment: The carbonyl group would be on compound A which is oxidated compound B. So I expect B to instead have a hydroxy group.